# Predefined class properties if need expand or shrink quantity of them on each app start

Tags: vb.net, list, class

```
    Public Class Products
           Private zCriteria As String
                Public Property Criteria As String
                    Get
                        Return zCriteria
                    End Get
                    Set(value As String)
                        zCriteria = value
                    End Set
                End Property

                Private zProductList As New List(Of Product)
                Public Property ProductList As List(Of Product)
                    Get
                        Return zProductList
                    End Get
                    Set(value As List(Of Product))
                        zProductList = value
                    End Set
                End Property

            End Class
Public Class Product
            Private zCriteriaList As List(Of Criterias)
            Public Property CriteriaList As List(Of Criterias)
                Get
                    Return zCriteriaList
                End Get
                Set(value As List(Of Criterias))
                    zCriteriaList = value
                End Set
            End Property
    End Class

    Public Class Criterias
            Private zCrPropName As String
            Public Property CrPropName As String
                Get
                    Return zCrPropName
                End Get
                Set(value As String)
                    zCrPropName = value
                End Set
            End Property
            Private zCritCode As String
            Public Property CritCode As String
                Get
                    Return zCritCode
                End Get
                Set(value As String)
                    zCritCode = value
                End Set
            End Property
            Private zcrPropValue As String
            Public Property crPropValue As String
                Get
                    Return zcrPropValue
                End Get
                Set(value As String)
                    zcrPropValue = value
                End Set
            End Property
        End Class

        For Each oProducts As Products In oAssigment.ProductsList
          For Each oproduct As Product In oProducts.ProductList
             For Each cr As Criterias In oproduct.CriteriaList
                 cr.CrPropName = "Product Name" 'some object property name
                 cr.CritCode = "PN"
                cr.crPropValue = "" ' Value of property "Product Name"
             Next
          Next
        Next
```

It is all made to have different properties of some object depending on options set in text file. It is only a sample o usage.

conditions: 
Criterias on applications start is same for all objects (=Product) i want to read.
Every time on start, application read options file where is defined few property names and codes (values i want get from objects). So every run can be initiated different quantity of properties to read. It means i can not have hard-coded names of properties.

Someone can advice me how to predefine "CrPropName" and "CritCode" on app start so many times how much property names defined in options and after that populate it so many times as how many objects exist from which i read these property values.

p.s. I am not very professional at coding and sorry for my language

Comment: what ist that for a language?

Comment: Please add a tag for your question. I suppose it would be Visual Basic.